# How to remote invocate php file?

Tags: php, xmlhttprequest

I can visit url "http://localhost:8080/test.php?dbname=zhenhuang",but the following code does not work.I want to know how to invocate php file in javascript.

```
var http=new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.onreadystatechange=function(){
        console.log(http.readyState);enter code here
        if(http.readyState === 4){
            /*code*/
        }
    };
    http.open("GET","http://localhost:8080/test.php?dbname=zhenhuang",true);
    http.send(null);
<pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get that page's content, you can just:

```
 $result = file_get_contents("http://localhost:8080/test.php?dbname=zhenhuang");
```

Read more [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

I hope it helps! :)